# Backbone: how to reuse a view rendered during page load

Tags: backbone.js

I am creating an url manager where user can bookmark his favorite webpage URLs and then manage them in folders.

1. During app load, I render a view which shows the list of folders user has created. this view is invisible on page load.
2. then user navigates to his home page to see a list of urls
3. from there, user can arrange the urls in folders
4. user clicks the 'Move to folder' icon in URL view
5. I want to display the folderSelectorView absolute positioned below the 'Move to Folder' icon. How can I do that?
6. Also if the url has already been moved to a folder, I want a checked sign to appear in the folderSelectorView in the folder where the url has been moved to.

How should I proceed here?

Here is how I load the list of folders.

```
var folderColl = new FolderColl();
new FolderSelectorView({collection: folderColl});
```

Here is the code for URL view.

```
URLView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template($('#URLTempalte').html()),
    events: {
        'click .FolderChange': 'showFolderSelector'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

    render: function() {
        return $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },

    showFolderSelector: function() {
       // How should I display the view here
       // view should display below the "Move to folder" icon
       // Doing something like `new FolderSelectorView` is not what I'm after
       // since that will just re-render the view for every URL displayed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can attach a backbone view to an existing HTML element, easily. all you need to do is pass the `el` for the view, into the view when you instantiate it. the `el` can be anything you want - including an existing html element, found through a jQuery selector.

```
var myEl = $("#someElementOnThePage");
var myView = new MyView({
  el: myEl
});
```

This will attach your view to the `#someElementOnThePage` element, and you can then use it as if you had rendered it yourself.

For more examples, see my blog post on progressive elaboration: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/